# Relay.Store.commitUpdate never commits

Tags: react-native, graphql, relayjs

I have recently started using **Relay** on my **React Native** app, but mutations never seem to be committing (I don't get any logging from the success/fail callbacks), nor am I getting anything in the `console.log` in the `resolve` function of my **GraphQL** implementation.

I have the following code in my root Component of my app.
I actually don't need the updated name to be shown in my app, it is merely for updating the DB.

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new DogMutation({name: 'Stack'}, {
            onSuccess: () => console.log("success"),
            onFailure: (transaction) => console.error(transaction)
        ))
    }
}
```

The mutation class looks like this:

```
export default class DogMutation extends Mutation {
    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on Dog {
                name
            }
        `
    }

    getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation {renameDog}`
    }

    getVariables() {
        return {
            name: this.props.name
        }
    }

    getConfigs() {
        return []
    }
}
```

The **GraphQL** side mutation code looks like this:

```
export const renameDog = {
    type: Dog,
    description: `Rename a dog.`,
    args: {
        input: {
            type: new GraphQLInputObjectType({
                name: `DogInput`,
                fields: {
                    name: {
                        type: GraphQLString,
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    },
    async resolve (obj, args) {
        console.log(args) <- Which never outputs
    }
}
```

When I call `Relay.Store.commitUpdate()`, I get:

```
RelayMutationQueue.js:390 Optimistic query for `renameDog`
RelayMutationQueue.js:454 Mutation query for `renameDog`
```

in my React Native Chrome Debugger.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Could I be missing something from the multiple articles I've read?
My hunch was that I'm using `Relay.Store` directly instead of creating one somewhere and passing it as `props`, but understand that this is a global instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a simple one which took ages for me to find until [josephsavona](https://github.com/josephsavona) helped me in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1467).

The callback was never called because those do not belong in the initialization of the mutation, rather, it is the second argument to the `commitUpdate` function.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js)'s `mutationWithClientMutationId` function and it seems to actually commit the message, but still no callback from the mutation.

Comment: Hello, what does the "network" tab of the Chrome Debugger outputs ? Is there a request sent ?

Comment: Also, can you try wrapping your App in a Container and a RootContainer and calling `this.props.relay` instead ?

Comment: @whitep4nther I tried doing `this.props.relay.commitUpdate({name:'foo'})`, it's hitting GraphQL, but there is no call back or anything.

Comment: sounds strange. Can you try to update your server directly using your mutation and GraphiQL ? So we can be sure the server part is working properly.

Comment: @whitep4nther Mutations using GraphiQL are working fine. My app can now achieve a mutation, i.e. send login credentials and get back a token, but that token can never be received since the `onSuccess` or `onFailure` is never called. Do you know when these are triggered? I can confirm that GraphQL is returning data to the app from a `console.log` right before the `return` in the `resolve()`.

Comment: Are you correctly implementing `getFatQuery()` ? I guess this might be fixed using `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` config. Anyways, for now it is recommended to implement login/logout outside of Relay. The best way to do it is to reset environment on logout.

Comment: Anyways, your onSuccess and onFailure handlers should be called. Can you post your whole code on Git or something ? If you wish to. I can try on my computer.

Comment: @whitep4nther Thank you. I'll post a Gist within an hour

Comment: Oh, if it's generally recommended by the community that I don't use Relay for login/logout, I might not use it then. Thank you for your help though.